# Is there a md5 checksum generator for windows ce

Tags: windows-ce, md5

I need a command line tool for windows ce to generate md5 checksums recursively from a directory and preferably generate a xml file as a result.

Does anybody know such a tool? I have searched the internet all over, including this page, but could not find one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use dump.exe from the RAPI tools. Get it here: http://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/xda/tools.html . Quote from their page:

> using the -md5, -sha1, -sha256, -crc or -sum options, you can use
>   dump.exe to calculate the checksum, crc or hash of a specific region
>   of a file

Comment: dump.exe can't be used for generating file checksums recursively from a directory.